# Can a Backbone.js View have a Model and a Collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational, backbone-views

Can a Backbone.js `View` have a `Model` and a `Collection`?

The reason I am asking is because I'm working with a View that holds a map with places plotted on it (using the leaflet library).

The `Collection` is of a group of models that hold coordinates to be plotted on the map.

The `Model` holds stuff like the map bounds and map shape.

Not sure how else to pull this one off...

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can pass it in as simply as:

```
new view({model: m, collection: c});
```

and inside the view you can access both with:

```
this.model
this.collection
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/delvarworld/P3Y9x/1/) for example

Comment: I also find useful (for readability and ease of support) to rename `model` and `collection` to something more meaningful. E. g. `new MapView({map: mapModel, markers: markersCollection})`. If you opt to do this, don't forget to access them via `this.options.map` or add `this.map = this.options.map; this.markers = this.options.markers` to your map view's `initialize` method.

Comment: jsfiddle now gives a 404